# How can I fill DataGrid depending of the content of two ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I'm new at WPF and I've been away from c# for years. I used to develop my basic GUIs at WindowsForms. Anyway, I cannot figure out how to update a datagrid from a combination of two comboboxes.

Here's the overview.

Each combobox has its own DataTable, same case with the DataGrid.

When I select an item from ComboboxA, ComboBoxB should display the result of its query depending of what I've selected in ComboBox A and the DataGrid will be filled with its query result from the combination of the 2 selected items in each ComboBox.

Here's what I've achieved.

I can select any item from ComboboxA and retrieve all the items for ComboBoxB depending of what I've selected. I coded to display only the first index of ComboboxB any time I click on any item from ComboboxA and then it will fill my datagrid. Lets call this the default case.

But, when I want to select an item from ComboBox A and I want to select a different item, which means different from the default index[0],from ComboboxB and display the result of this combination to my DataGrid, my code crashes.

I've managed to display the content of my comboboxB depending on the item selected at comboboxA, however I want also to display the data from my DataGrid depending of what I've selected on my comboboxB.

NOTE:
If I add code to the ComboboxBSelectionChanged event, the default case will not work because it will always returned a null value.

Here's my code:

```
private void Cmb_LineNames_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_LineNames.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Value. Select a valid line.");
        }
        else
        {
            cmb_SelectYear.Items.Clear();
            linename = cmb_LineNames.SelectedValue.ToString();
            syDT = dataHandler.GetCurrentYear(linename);
            selectedYear = dataHandler.fillSelectedYearCmb(syDT,cmb_SelectYear); 
            if(selectedYear != 0)
            {
                mcDT = dataHandler.GetMountedComponentsPerLine(linename, selectedYear);
                dataHandler.DisplayMountedComponents(mcDT, dgvMountedComponents);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Cmb_SelectYear_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //int selectYear = 0;
        //selectYear = int.Parse(cmb_SelectYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
        //mcDT = dataHandler.GetMountedComponentsPerLine(linename, selectYear);
        //dataHandler.DisplayMountedComponents(mcDT, dgvMountedComponents);
    }
```

dataHandlerClass that has the Fill method to the ComboboxB

```
public int fillSelectedYearCmb(ScrapIDataSet.SelectYearDataTable yearRows, ComboBox cmbBox)
    {
        int selectedYear = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < yearRows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmbBox.Items.Add(yearRows.Rows[i]["Year"]);
        }
        cmbBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        selectedYear = int.Parse(cmbBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
        return selectedYear;
    }

    public void DisplayMountedComponents(ScrapIDataSet.MountedComponentsPerLineDataTable mountedComponentsPerLineRows, DataGrid dataGridMC)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mountedComponentsPerLineRows.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridMC.DataContext = mountedComponentsPerLineRows.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

ComboboxA is cmb_LineNames
ComboboxB is cmb_SelectYear

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: on which line exactly does it crash?

Comment: I suggest you consider mvvm.  Selectionchanged fires before the new value is selected. I think you'd need to defer checking the new value using dispatcher.invokeasync or some such to get the new value in your handler. The pattern I would recommend is to bind selecteditem and act in the setter. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged